# How to calculate LCM value using SQL Server?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2012

I have below data and I need to calculate LCM (Lowest calculate multiply) value based on group id using a T-SQL query. Your help would be appreciated.

```
Groupid GroupValue
------------------
1        2
1        4
1        6
2        5
2        5
2       10
3        3
3       12
3        6
3        9
```

Expected result is below.

```
Groupid   GroupLCM
------------------
   1        12
   2        10
   3        36
```

Comment: SQL isn't a good language for mathematically breaking a number down into prime factors.

Comment: Doable in pure T-SQL, but neither obvious nor efficient. If you needed this as part of a "real" database (not a toy exercise) I'd probably make it a CLR custom aggregate; `lcm(a,b) = a / gcd(a,b) * b`, and `gcd` is the oldest algorithm in the book. (Literally.)

Answer (score 2):

One possible way is to use tally tables like below

<kbd>**[See working demo](http://rextester.com/IUKS35837)**</kbd>

```
; with detailedSet as 
(
    select 
        Groupid,
        GroupValue=abs(GroupValue),
        biggest=max(GroupValue) over (partition by Groupid),
        totalNumbers= count(1) over (partition by Groupid)
    from num
    )
,   
possibleLCMValues as 
(
    select Groupid, counter
    from detailedSet b
    cross apply 
    (
select counter= row_number() over ( order by (select null))  * biggest 
from sys.objects o1 cross join sys.objects o2
)c
where c.counter%GroupValue =0
group by Groupid, counter
having count(1)=max(totalNumbers)
)
,
LCMValues as
(
    select 
        Groupid,
        LCM=min(counter) 
    from possibleLCMValues
    group by Groupid
)

select * from LCMValues
```

Comment: I suggest two slight tweaks: 1) to prevent nonsensical results if a group contains only negative numbers, use `abs(GroupValue)` and `max(abs(GroupValue))` in `detailedSet` (`lcm(a,b) = lcm(|a|,|b|)`). 2) change `c.counter < biggest * biggest` to `c.counter / biggest < biggest` to stave off integer overflow.

Comment: Thank you for your help. But when I have insert one more group id 4 with value 8,9,23 and validate the result then I am not getting group id 4 value in final result set. Might be some condition was not satisfied.

Comment: @Nikunj Yes. The product of other numbers was greater than largest number's square. I decided to remove the stop criteria.

Comment: I am facing some strange issue like when I run same query from http://rextester.com  in my ssms then query goes into infinite loop. But it run properly in that link. Any one can check you are also facing the same issue.

Comment: Dhruv, Just I inform you like query makes cross join between sys.objects. If your database having more than 1K objects then query goes running and running.. So remove the condition is not the optimize solution.

Comment: @Nikunj The cross join is called Tally table. It's a very quick form of in memory table. of course it's a hack based on sys.objects to create a counter in memory quickly. You should add a stopping criteria to cross apply in form of say a where clause which ends the tally to a finite list. But you need to ask yourself a question, at the maximum condition how many co-prime numbers can be in a group? also what's the largest LCM value you are targeting?

Comment: @Nikunj to use another form of tally check here [http://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/Tally+Table/72993/]

Comment: @Dhruv Can you please explain this Tally table with some example. so far  my concept it's not clear. Also I am not fixed largest LCM value because this value purely based on user input.

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution which I post on below stack flow question. In Final result table we just use max value again group id and we get LCM value.

Just note Like, I post this question for more optimize solution to remove for loop otherwise it working properly using for loop as well.

[How to update the column without loop in SQL Server?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52321558/how-to-update-the-column-without-loop-in-sql-server/52329975)